# Firebase App Check not working with firebase functions - web project

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-app-check

We are trying to use App Check but our firebase function that is accessing the realtime database and is displaying this error:
`FIREBASE WARNING: Invalid appcheck token`

We are using the latest versions of firebase-admin (9.9.0) and firebase-functions (3.14.1). And we are also using the latest version of firebase js SDK (8.6.7) on the frontend. But it is not working, the app check token is present on the function on `context.app` and on the request header but the error is still showing:

[image]

Is there anything else that we can try to make it work?

EDIT: We created a minimal code example that reproduce the error, you can see it here https://github.com/glauberramos/app-check-bug

Comment: Does your origin match your app check configuration? Locally emulated sites will have a different token to a deployed one.

Comment: We are testing on firebase hosting and the error is still there. What do you mean by app check configuration? The only configuration needed is the Recaptcha token, there is no configuration.

Comment: We created a repository to reproduce the error, the code is very simple https://github.com/glauberramos/app-check-bug